# using Sass nested selector in next js

Tags: sass, next.js

Why doesn't it work?

i wanna *change theme* or *active menu* something like that...

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to convert your "dark" class into `styles.dark` and maybe not need to be nasted selector.

```
.wrapper {
  ...code;
}

.dark {
  background-color:black;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you’re setting ‘isDark’ to be equal to the variable ’prev’  however ‘prev’ isn’t specified in your code anywhere try this instead.

```
onClick{() => setIsDark(!isDark)}
```

Also what Manfre said, your conditional class is a global use of ‘dark’ as a class, you need to specify as ‘{styles.dark}’